# RxJava combineLatest source order

Tags: android, rx-java2

In my Android app, I have 2 editText and one textView. I use RxJava in my app. I want the text view to show the the combination of two editable text fields.

I use Observable.combineLates as follow:

```
    EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);
    EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_2);


    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Observable<String> s1 =  RxTextView.textChanges(editText1).map(CharSequence::toString);
    Observable<String> s2 =  RxTextView.textChanges(editText2).map(CharSequence::toString);

    Observable<String> source = Observable.combineLatest(s1,s2, (c1,c2)->c1+" "+c2);

    source.subscribe(textView::setText);
```

When I run the app I see the text view shows its content in reverse order, that is the text from source 2 appears before the source from text 1. Only when I swap s2 with s2 inside combineLatest it works as expected. 
Any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse order"?

Comment: The only thing missing is the layout file, so is the layout correct?

Comment: The layout consist of 2 editText and one Textiew below them. Say for example I enered "Hi" in the first editText and "There" in second editText, what I see in the text view is "There Hi"

Comment: Please check that your combiner function uses the right variables, i.e., you didn't accidentally wrote `c2 + " " + c1`.

Comment: Also as Euge said, please check that editText1 is actually your first/top edit box and your variable naming is consistent.